# How to add to mySQL database my dynamically added rows from my FORM using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am just a newbie in using PHP and mySQl. I am currently developing or creating a web app system that can be used to dynamically add rows and put it in my database. here's the snippet.

function addTerms(){

```
        var table = document.getElementById('contractterms');
        var lastRow = table.rows.length;
        var iteration = lastRow;

        var row = table.insertRow(lastRow);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var contractTermName = document.createElement('input');
        contractTermName.type = 'text';
        contractTermName.name = 'termName' + iteration;
        contractTermName.id = 'termName' + iteration;
        cell1.appendChild(contractTermName);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var contractSummary = document.createElement('textarea');
        contractSummary.name = 'termSummary' + iteration;
        contractSummary.id = 'termSummary' + iteration;
        contractSummary.cols = "50";
        cell2.appendChild(contractSummary);
    }
```

How can I add the values from my added rows to my database? I already tried searching answers but It couldn't help me. It wasn't working at all. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your function addTerms() is written in Javascript which runs on client side. You need to grab the freshly added data and send it via ajax request to your server, i.e. a PHP script that finally inserts the data into your MySQL database.

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for your reply. Hmm. Can you just give me even a code sample on how to grab the added data? I am really new on this :(

Comment: Well, you do create the form elements within your table already and give them IDs. Use these IDs to get the form elements value. Basically, you are looking for document.getElementById('termname'+iteration).value (for both inputs and textareas). Of course, you need a basic understanding of javascript and some library like jQuery will really help you with ajax requests.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what you are trying to achieve. Your code adds rows to a table. These table rows contain an input and a textarea (both without value). So, is it possible to alter all values at once? After insertion of a row you need an action to save the data AFTER it has been entered. Your intended workflow is not really clear by reading your question.

Comment: Oh sorry. what I want to do is, after I clicked the add row button, the added rows will be appended to the last row. then I should input data there. After I clicked the save button, the rows should be added to my table. my table name is contract_terms. and there are three columns. one for the id, second is for the term_name and the third one is for the term_summary.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to take a look at [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).

Comment: I know this one. My problem is, I have dynamically added rows every time I click the add row button, it will add another row, or another set of values that will be inserted to the database.